# Scraping AJAX requests with random strings appended to URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping

I am trying to monitor cricket scores on [scorespro/cricket](http://www.scorespro.com/cricket/) by making browser AJAX requests. Analysing the network traffic in Google Chrome, I can see my browser making requests of the form:

http://www.scorespro.com/cricket/ajax.php?g_sort=league&date=2014-10-02&mut=1412265716&sut=0&(some_random_number)

When I click on the response IN Google Chrome, I can see the data that has been received. However when I try to request the request URL myself, no data is received. Why is that happening (is it to do with the random string) and how can I get around it?

Comment: Can you provide a working URL example?

Comment: http://www.scorespro.com/cricket/ajax.php?g_sort=league&date=2014-10-02&mut=1412266581&sut=0&0.004229517187923193

Comment: `url: livescoresPath + "/ajax.php?g_sort=" + g_sort + "&date=" + temp_page_date + "&mut=" + match_ut + "&sut=" + score_ut + "&" + Math.random(),` Value at the end means nothing it is just a cache buster.

Comment: Looks like they are sniffing the referrer, looks like you are out of luck and need to pay. ;)

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I thought. But then I don't understand why the link does not work a second time? With regards to the referrer, you mean the referrer header?

Comment: I can always just use headless browser to get data so its not a big problem, I just don't understand how they are stopping the AJAX request

Comment: @epascarello ok kl, that worked :)

Comment: The link does work a second time. Open up the dev console and do `$.get("http://www.scorespro.com/cricket/ajax.php?g_sort=league&date=2014-10-02&mut=1412265716&sut=0")`

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that comment but I found that changing the referer header was the way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is doing this from javascript a requirement?  Have you considered abstracting the requests by calling a script on a server you control?

For example on your server you could have a PHP script called, for example, "grabber.php"

```
<?php
$r = '0.' . rand(1000000000000000, 9000000000000000);

$url = 'http://www.scorespro.com/cricket/ajax.php?g_sort=league&date=2014-10-03&mut=1412328280&sut=0&' . $r;
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0';
$referer = 'http://www.scorespro.com/cricket/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$data = array('payload' => $response);

echo json_encode($data);

exit();

?>
```

You could then call that page via a simple ajax request :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourserver.com/grabber.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if (data['payload']){
            alert(data['payload']);
        } else {
            alert ('oops');
        }
    }
});
```

Of course if you went with this approach you'd have to decide how to get the URL's you need to request from the cricket site to the grabber script (i.e. pass them from javascript or get them directly from within the PHP script depending on your requirements)